# Define generic function type

Tags: generics, inheritance, anonymous-function, nim-lang

Given the following snippet:

```
type
  Base = object of RootObj
  Consume*[T: Base] = proc(e: T): bool
```

I want to define several types from base and base consumer for it, like this:

```
type
  BaseOne = object of Base
  ConsumeOne = Consume[BaseOne]
```

Now, when i create a new `ConsumeOne`:

```
let co: ConsumeOne = proc(b: BaseOne): bool = false
```

I get the following compiler error:`Error: type mismatch: got (proc (b: BaseOne): bool{.gcsafe, locks: 0.}) but expected 'ConsumeOne'`

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that type class constraints for type parameters currently do not match subtypes; I do not know if that is a bug or intentional. For now, simply remove the `: Base` constraint from the type parameter `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would help to make Consume gcsafe:

```
Consume*[T: Base] = proc(e: T): bool {.gcsafe.}
```